# how edit names of field in django filters, and add styling

Tags: python, django, django-models, bootstrap-4

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Rct7Na0UQ&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=14&t=223s) to make a django app, I was making a filter table however there are some issues in it. I have already tried things suggested in other answers, and they did not work for me.
**In the image attached as you can see I have underlined the names of the fields that I want to change and don't know how to do it, django just named those fileds by itslef and I want to change it, also please tell how can I use bootstrap to make it look good.** Thank you..  [image]
filters.py file -

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import DateFilter, CharFilter
from . models import *


class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
start_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_created", lookup_expr="gte")  # lookup_expression, gte-> 
                                                                       # greater than or equal to
end_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_created", lookup_expr="gte")  # lookup_expression, lte-> less 
                                                                     # than or equal to
note = CharFilter(field_name="note", lookup_expr="icontains")

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = '__all__'
    # we are excluding these because we want to customize them
    exclude = ['customer', 'date_created']
```

model - Order - in models.py -

```
class Order(models.Model):
STATUS = (
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    ('Out for Delivery', 'Out for Delivery'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered')
    )
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=STATUS)
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this will surely help you. You can update the name of the field in `__init__` method like I did for note.

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['customer', 'date_created']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['note'].extra.update(
            {'empty_label': 'Note'})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Prabhjot Singh already answered the first question which is how to change the labeling of the fields... As for styling them with bootstrap a great way would be to install Django-crispy-forms and then use it when rendering the form in your template, check the documentation to know how to use it... https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ if you still are facing problems with it, comment below I will share a full guide tomorrow if you need it.